# Using Twitter bootstrap - can I change the ordering of rows and columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two rows with three columns in each. The first row contains images, the second row contains areas with text. In a desktop browser - where the three columns are aligned horizontally - each image is aligned on top of the corresponding text area.
But on a mobile device, of course, all columns are stacked below each other.
This makes all the images in row one get displayed below each other. And then the text areas follow in the same manner.

Is there a css-way to re-arrange my columns? I would like to stack the image and its corresponding text area together like this:

```
image1
textArea1
image2
textArea2
image3
textArea3
```

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsdcg/2/) set up.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span4"> <div class="span4"> <div class="span4">
<div class="row">
<div class="span4"> <div class="span4"> <div class="span4">
```

No images but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using bootstrap 3.0.

This is a very common layout situation.
You have a couple of options.

You can use the inbuilt bootstrap column reordering with offset, if you place all of your columns in the same container and handle them accordingly on the various views. However this has to do mostly with rearranging the order that contents are displayed and not optimal for this particular case but have a look on how this work as it will come in handy in various scenarios in the future.

[Bootstrap 3.0 offsets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

But the most proper solution in your case and the one I use extensively in cases like this, is to put the image and text on the same columns like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="..."/>
        <p>...image text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="..."/>
        <p>...image text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="..."/>
        <p>...image text here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you have a column that displays correctly on all views.

Remember that bootstrap 3 is mobile first and developing should start ideally, from the smallest view to the largest.
Always try to keep relevant dom elements together so that they have the desirable behavior on different sized layouts.

You just need to make sure that your image is equal or bigger than your larger column space width and that you use the *img-responsive* class on the image, for it to scale properly.

There are also other ways to achieve this but they defeat the purpose of using bootstrap for responsive layout and will more complicated for no good reason and similar result.

Try to keep markup as simple and elegant as possible in bootstrap for better maintenance, or things can easily get lost in a code soup of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Have yo tried putting rows into your spans?

Like

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span4">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="spanX">...</div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="spanX">...</div>
       </div>
   </div>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using rows for displaying images and relative information below you can use thumbnails of twitter bootstrap like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html
here is example

```
    <ul class="thumbnails">
<li class="span4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
<h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
<p>Thumbnail caption...</p>
</div>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here:

http://fittopage.org/2012/09/11/vertical-reordering-in-css/

There is also a directive in CSS3, but it's not rolled out yet as far as I know.

**Update:** In css3 it's called flexbox but currently only chrome supports some of it's features. More info [here](http://benfrain.com/understanding-the-css3-flexbox-flexible-box-layout-module/)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just putting each image and corresponding text in the same row and column.
Text below image.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap 3x?

The new grid system lets you set your own span sizes for different screen sizes, that way you could make sure all your rows line up the way you want.

Example:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-xs-1"></div>
```

Check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting some  after the rows. I think you can put it something like this structure

```
<div class = "container">
 <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-12">
   <div class = "box-container">
    <div class = "image">
     <img href="path/to/image.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class = "paragraph">
     <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amit...</p>
    </div>
   </div><!-- end of box container-->
   <div class = "box-container">
    <div class = "image">
     <img href="path/to/image.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class = "paragraph">
     <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amit...</p>
    </div>
   </div><!-- end of box container-->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then put some width for your box container and paragraph container.

You can also do it a different way. This will automatically stack when your on mobile view.

```
<div class = "container">
     <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-4">
       <div class = "box-container">
        <div class = "image">
         <img href="path/to/image.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class = "paragraph">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amit...</p>
        </div>
       </div><!-- end of box container-->
      </div><!-- 1st box-->
      <div class = "col-md-4">
       <div class = "box-container">
        <div class = "image">
         <img href="path/to/image.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class = "paragraph">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amit...</p>
        </div>
       </div><!-- end of box container-->
      </div><!-- 2nd box-->
      <div class = "col-md-4">
       <div class = "box-container">
        <div class = "image">
         <img href="path/to/image.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class = "paragraph">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amit...</p>
        </div>
       </div><!-- end of box container-->
      </div><!-- 3rd box-->

     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        image1
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        textArea1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        image2
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        textArea2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        image3
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        textArea3
    </div>
</div>
```

i hope it works.